# ASP.NET MVC Post for @Url.action()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have the following controller auto-generated by asp.net

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/LogOff
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Now I have a log off button.  Currently it looks like this:

```
   <div class="userdrop">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Manage", "Account")">Profile</a></li>                       
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--userdrop-->
```

But it does not work and I am guessing it is cause it is a Post action method.

How would I go about "logging off" ?

[EDIT]

Why is it auto-generated as an Http Post? Is it more secure that way? Does it not send the cookie with it when it logs out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How would I go about "logging off" ?

By using a form instead of an anchor:

```
<li>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account"))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <button type="submit">Logout</button>
    }
</li>
```

You could call the CSS wizards to style this button look like an anchor if you want. But the semantically correct element in this case is an html form which allows you to send a POST verb.

Comment: +1 for the `submit` button code - and as a side-note here, I've had significant problems with `AntiForgeryToken` on load balanced shared hosting environments. Do you know of a solution for that problem? It's why I've stopped including it in my forms and I don't like it at all. It's likely the OP may as well.

Comment: @darin Good solution. Anyway to keep the two elements the same? As my css now displays a button and not the same view as above?

Comment: I think I answered my own question by looking at another one of your answers. The key is to put the `machineKey` in the `Web.config` so that it's consistent across all instances of the application. I had to do that to solve a different problem, the "Keep me logged in" problem. I now wonder this though - what are the risks associated with it?

Comment: @Zapnologica, yes a submit button doesn't look the same as an anchor. So all you have to do is use CSS to make it look as you wish. I am not a CSS specialist, you could start a separate question on this topic. The answer to your question though here is to use a form and a submit button which will allow you to send a POST request and the antiforgery token.

Answer (score 7):

There is no compelling reason for this to be an `HttpPost`. I know it's generated that way, but you're not actually `POST`ing any data. Just remove the attribute and it will work as is.

Now, if you want it to work with the `HttpPost` then you'll need to wrap this in a `Form` and make it a `submit` button **or** `submit` the form `onclick`.

```
<li>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account",
        FormMethod.Post, new { id = "LogOffForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <a href="@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")"
            onclick="$('#LogOffForm').submit();">Logout</a>
    }
</li>
```

Comment: + 1 for another workaround.  Some CSS frameworks and templates won't like the added from in there. The LogOff action also requires the anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" by default.  The         [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute should be removed as well. I struggled with the ramifications of this abit....but after all, it is limited to DE-Auth

Comment: is there any security concerns with removing the anti-forgery token and making in a get rather than a post?

Comment: POST should be used so it forces the browser to hit the server.  Using GET, the browser could use a cached copy and not properly log the user off of the server.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that it has to do with `[HttpPost]` attribute, which only allow for HTTP POST requests to be made. Regular HTML anchors trigger HTTP GET requests, therefor your example does not work.

One solution would be something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, 
          new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button type="submit">Log off</button>
}
```

I believe this is close to what the default template does in MVC4.

*Notice how we also pass along the anti forgery token, required by the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute.*

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud LOL, I removed the need for JS altogether now.