# Create Linked Database Record in MVC5 Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm just starting out with ASP.NET MVC, and anything but the basics throws me at the moment, so please bear with me.

I am writing a little application á la [UserVoice](//www.uservoice.com/), whereby users can post ideas, and other users can vote for those posts.

I have a View which displays the detail of a particular Post (suggestion). On that View I have button labelled Vote which, when clicked, should create a record in my database's PostVote table linked to the Post. I just can't get this work, though! Here's what I have:

**Post > Details.cshtml**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("VoteForPost", "PostVote", new { id = Model.PostID })" class=" btn btn-success">Vote</a>
```

**PostVoteController.cs**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult VoteForPost(int id, Post post)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         db.PostVote.Add(new PostVote
         {
             PostID = id,
             VoteTime = DateTime.Now,
             VoteUser = UserHelper.GetUsername()
         });
         db.SaveChanges();                
     }
     return View(post);
 }
```

The only reason I'm requiring the `post` parameter in my method is because, as I understand it, unless I want to use Ajax I need to use an ActionResult and return a View, and so I've tried to copy the code in the Edit method of the `PostController` which was generated automatically by Visual Studio and works fine. The idea is just to reload the Post Details View after the new PostVote record has been created,

I realise I've probably written nonsense, but nothing I'm trying works. When I click the Vote button, I'm directed to a page with a URL of `http://localhost:58974/PostVote/VoteForPost/1`, which I sort of understand, but is obviously wrong. I can't figure out how to just pass the ID of the Post to which the new PostVote record should be linked as a variable rather than it forming part of the URL. Obviously I get a 404 error because the page doesn't exist.

**Update**
Ok, thanks to the comments posted I've now got this in my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("VoteForPost", "PostVote", new { id = Model.PostID }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <button type="submit">Vote</button>
}
```

This is successfully creating the records as desired, but is still trying to redirect the browser to `http://localhost:58974/PostVote/VoteForPost/1` afterwards. Bearing mind that the Controller (PostView.cs) doing the record creation is not the one which displayed the Post Details in the first place (that's Post.cs), how do I get my method to just return me back to the Details View I'm already looking at?

Comment: `<a href="...">`does not submit a POST request when you click but it simply does a get request.

Comment: You could use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406497/asp-net-mvc-post-for-url-action).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm making progress, but I've updated my question with what's now happening.